# How to add properties to an object that is inside an array of objects with useState hook

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I have an array of objects created from useState hook:

```
const [arrayOfObjects, setArrayOfObjects] = useState([]);

setArrayOfObjects([{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]);
```

How do I add a property to each object through the setArrayOfObjects function so that it will be:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  name: "one",
 },
 {
  id:2,
  name: 'two',
 },
 {
  id:3,
  name: 'three',
 },
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for that you can use the map operator in the array type. That will return a new array with your data transformed (mapped) to something else like this:

```
let newarrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(e => {
return {
  id: e.id,
  name: someVariableWithTheName,
 }
});
setArrayOfObjects(newarrayOfObjects);
```

if you need the index of the element to do something the map method actually takes two arguments, first the element and second the index of the element so code can be use as this:

```
let newarrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(e, index => {
return {
  id: e.id,
  name: index,
 }
});
setArrayOfObjects(newarrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the array to add and use JavaScript array map function.

```
const additionalArr = [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name: 'three'}];
const newArrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map((obj, idx) => ({
  ...obj,
  ...additionalArr[idx]
}));

setArrayOfObjects(newArrayOfObjects);
```